# How to denote the action of a unitary transformation on a register?

Tags: terminology-and-notation

Suppose we have a quantum register $\lvert ab \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\lvert 00 \rangle + \lvert 11 \rangle)$. I want to denote the action of the transformation $X \otimes I_2$ on this register. I tried to write this as

$$\lvert Xa \rangle \otimes \lvert I_2b \rangle$$

, but I think we can not do this, since $\lvert ab \rangle$ is an entangled state and thus has no representation as a product. But what is the right way to denote the action $X \otimes I_2$ on $\lvert ab \rangle$?

Comment: No you can't do that.  First of all, it's not right to write an entangled state as $|ab\rangle$.  What you can do is to write as $X\otimes I_2\frac1{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle) = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}(|10\rangle+|01\rangle)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Guangliang, if you have two quantum registers $a,b$ which are known to be entangled (in this case maximally entangled), their state is said to be *not separable*. Namely, there is no way of writing their state as a tensor product of the two **register's state** without losing information. I.e. $|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle$ is wrong, and so is $|ab\rangle$.

You need to distinguish a register from its state to understand this. You can use register names $a,b$ as subscript that highlight where quantum information is stored. E.g.
$$|\Phi_{ab}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0_a0_b\rangle + |1_a1_b\rangle).$$

If you want to bring the bit-flip operation as to appear within the state, you could do something like the following:
$$X\otimes I|\Phi_{ab}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\lnot 0_a0_b\rangle + |\lnot1_a1_b\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1_a0_b\rangle + |0_a1_b\rangle).$$